# coupon vs voucher difference

Tags: differences

I am studying the difference between coupon and voucher. I talked to three natives today:

US guy: voucher can be used only once, and it is either a discount or you can have a sample product for free.

US guy number 2: coupons can be used repeteadly until its credit is used up.

UK guy: voucher is more common in the UK, coupon in the US

hypothesis: Maybe that coupons are sold for a particular value, eg 20 USD each coupon. And someone has eg 5 of them. Voucher means a discount from the purchase that you make.

hypothesis: Maybe they use these two words differently in the UK and US.

Wikipedia writes that voucher is a synonyme for receipt. That confuses me a bit. Does it have more meanings?

What is the difference?

wiki pages

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voucher

Thank you.

Comment: In Australia a "gift voucher" is like your US explanation of "coupon", it has an opening balance that (in most cases) does not have to be used in a single purchase, you can use it over a number of occasions until the balance gets down to zero. But we also have single-use vouchers for a specific purpose, e.g., a voucher for a free doughnut.

Answer (score 1):

In the OED the noun ***coupon*** has four principal senses and many sub-senses, but at its most general - sense 1. coupon means:

> A separable certificate or ticket, of which a series are attached to,
>   and form part of, certain original or principal certificates, in order
>   that they may be severally detached and given up as required.

Coupons can be used for many purposes - but in essence they are certificates which confirm some sort of (usually)commercial entitlement.

A ***voucher*** has a separate range of meanings, the older of which have a strictly legal essence e.g.

sense 1a:

> The summoning of a person into court to warrant the title to a
>   property. voucher over

sense 2a:

> transf. A piece of evidence; a fact, circumstance, or thing serving to
>   confirm or prove something; a guarantee.

sense 2b:

> A written document or note, or other material evidence, serving to
>   attest the correctness of accounts or monetary transactions, to prove
>   the delivery of goods or valuables, etc.

It is when you get to sense 2d, that ***voucher*** becomes synonymous with some of the senses of ***coupon***: But note that the earliest example of this rather everyday use is from 1947. 
sense 2d.

> d. A document which can be exchanged for goods or services as token of
>   payment made or promised by the holder or another (see also quot.
>   1947).
>
> 1947   Sun (Baltimore)  12 May 2/5   Stefan has gone through a stack
>   of vouchers—expense accounts—from the American Embassy.
>
> 1955   Evening Standard 28 Oct. 15/3 (heading)    Doorman/timekeeper
>   for staff and goods entrance... Pension scheme, welfare fund, luncheon
>   vouchers, etc.
>
> 1960   S. Unwin Truth about Publisher ii. xix. 353   The New Zealand
>   Company had not given me an actual ticket..but a voucher instructing
>   their agent to issue me a ticket.

**It seems clear that before and during WW2, *coupon* would have been the principle term for a commercial document proving entitlement. The UK's wartime food rationing system was based on *coupons*. But, from mid-century it would seem that the old legal term *voucher* gained prominence.**

Answer (score -1):

In U.S Retail sales, a coupon is applied after while a discount is applied before.

Say I am a wholesaler and I have several a high volume customer Name GREATCUSTOMER. I give GREATCUSTOMER a better price if they buy case quantities then my normal customers who buys just 1 of an item.

The base price of the item is adjusted for GREATCUSTOMER.
That is a Discount

Discounts are applied before any other calculations are done.
Such as TAX, VAT, Shipping (if it is based upon price), etc.

A coupon is different, a coupon normally does not adjust the base price of an item. And usually it taken off the total of the sale. (Some U.S. states treat coupons different, some require the coupon amount to be taken before tax is calculated and some states require coupon after tax is calculated (these states tax the base price of the item first, so sales tax is higher) In these later states, often retail stores offer "discounts" instead of regular coupons.

To sum it up, discount is taken before any calculations on an order are done. coupons after.

Usually a voucher can be exchanged for physical goods. Using it as a term for a reciept is an archaic usage of the term and not in common usage today.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please add a source to support your answer.